# Lsyncd(Live Syncing Daemon)で複数サーバをリアルタイム同期する

Tags: linux, rsync, lsyncd

http://liginc.co.jp/programmer/archives/4272
上記のサイトを参考にして行っているのですが、最後のところの

/etc/init.d/rsync start

がうまくいきません。
うまくいかないというか、ここにこのファイルが存在しないのです。
rsyncは
 /etc/xinetd.d/rsync
に存在しているので、こちらで
 /etc/xinetd.d/rsync　start
としてみたのですが、以下のようにエラーになってしまいます。

rsync: 認識されていないサービスです。
/etc/xinetd.d/rsync: line 6: disable: コマンドが見つかりません
/etc/xinetd.d/rsync: line 7: flags: コマンドが見つかりません
/etc/xinetd.d/rsync: line 8: socket_type: コマンドが見つかりません
/etc/xinetd.d/rsync: line 9: wait: `=': not a pid or valid job spec

/etc/xinetd.d/rsync: line 9: wait:`no': not a pid or valid job spec
/etc/xinetd.d/rsync: line 10: user: コマンドが見つかりません
/etc/xinetd.d/rsync: line 11: server: コマンドが見つかりません
/etc/xinetd.d/rsync: line 12: server_args: コマンドが見つかりません
/etc/xinetd.d/rsync: line 13: log_on_failure: コマンドが見つかりません

詳しい方、ご教示ください。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: `/etc/init.d/*` と `/etc/xinetd.d/*` は用途も形式も異なるため、代わりに使えばいいというものではないです。お使いのディストリビューション名（CentOSとかUbuntuとか）とバージョンを質問に追記していただけませんか？

Comment: すみません、初心者なので、ディストリビューションというのがよくわからないのですが、AWSを使っています！

Comment: 標準のものを使用しているので、恐らくcentOSになるのだろうと思います。バージョンはどのように表示すべきでしょうか？

Comment: ディストリビューションはAmazon Linux AMIのようです。

Comment: バージョンはAmazon Linux AMI release 2015.03
になります。

Answer (score 1):

rsync サービス(TCP 873番ポート)は xinetd 経由で起動しますので、"service xinetd start" (または "/etc/init.d/xinetd start")で xinetd が起動していればいいはずです。
xinetd プロセスが起動していること、"ss -tln" (または "netstat -tln") で :873 が LISTEN になっていることを確認してください。

URL の最後に起動するのは /etc/init.d/rsync ではなく /etc/init.d/lsyncd ではないですか？

Comment: LISTEN     0      64                       :::873                     :::*

Comment: 上記のようになっていました。
service xinetd startに関しては
xinetd を起動中:
okという風に出ないのですが、なぜでしょうか？

Comment: restartでokの表示が出ました。

Comment: /etc/init.d/rsync start
上記を実行すると、以下のようになってしまいます。 
/etc/init.d/rsync: そのようなファイルやディレクトリはありません

Comment: ちなみに以下も試してみましたが、以下のような結果になってしまいます。

sudo /usr/bin/rsync start




rsync: link_stat "/etc/rc.d/init.d/start" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1039) [sender=3.0.6]

Comment: URL を読み返して気づきました。
3の "/etc/init.d/rsync start" は必要ないと思います。
1,2 で xinetd を起動＆自動起動有効、この時点で xinetd 経由の rsync サービスが起動するはず。
念のため、4 で rsync サービスを有効にしています(/etc/xinetd.d/rsync の "disable = no")。

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。
サーバー①方で、index.htmlをアップロードしてみたのですが、サーバー②に同期されていないようです。。どのような原因が考えられるでしょうか？

Comment: ログファイル /var/log/rsyncd.log, /var/log/lsyncd.log には何かエラーが記録されていませんでしょうか。

Comment: そのようなファイルが見当たりません。なぜでしょうか？

Comment: CentOS 6 で URL の手順を試してみました。2点修正が必要でした。
(1) rsyncd.conf の誤植:[upload]→[uploads]に修正。
(2) lsyncd が起動していない。"service lsyncd start" (または、/etc/init.d/lsyncd start")が必要。

Comment: ご返信ありがとうございます。
/etc/init.d/lsyncd に確かにあるのですが、
/etc/init.d/lsyncd start
とすると、そのようなファイルやディレクトリはありません
となってしまいます。
どのような原因が考えられるでしょうか。

Comment: ファイルに実行権限が付いていないのだと思います。
"chmod a+x /etc/init.d/lsyncd" は実行しましたでしょうか。
あるいは、コンパイルした lsyncd を /usr/local/bin/lsyncd にインストールしていないのか。
私見ですが、Linux や rsync (特に "--delete" オプション)についてよく知らないのであれば、双方向で lsyncd を使うのはやめた方がいいと思います。
「作成したはずのファイルが消えている!?」ということになると思います。

Comment: ご返信ありがとうございます。
コンパイルしたlsyncdのインストールという手順はURL上にあるものとは違うのでしょうか？

片方向でlsyncdを使う方が、安全という意味でしょうか？